# Retrieve nodes content with PLSQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

Let's say I have a xml file in a directory (and the xsd too).

I would like to know the best ans easiest way to retrieve node content from this file.

Can I have some example of what to do ?

Let's work with this example of myfile.xml :

```
<root>
  <declaration>
     <id>12</id>
  </declaration>
</root>
```

Let's say I want to get the 12 id

ty

---

1. I want to get more than one node value. There are, for example, hundreds of declaration nodes, so I need to get hundreds of ids
2. The file is in a directory the database can see, thanks to the directory object... create directory ....

Comment: Do you want to extract value of a single particular node or several nodes?

Comment: Where is the file - on your client machine, or on the DB server; and in a directory the database can see (via an Oracle directory object)? Have you tried to read the file at all yet?

Answer (score 0):

One of many possibilities.

**Legned**

`XML_DIR` - oracle object directory with privileges.

`entrypoint.txt` - special file with it contains names of xmlfiles. Files have to exist in the same dir. This file have to be create separately.

```
xmlDocument1.xml
xmlDocument2.xml
etc...
```

Path structure.

```
    XML_DIR -|
             entrypoint.txt
             xmlDocument1.xml
             xmlDocument2.xml
```

Next you have to create external_table.

```
CREATE TABLE XML_EXTERNAL_DOCUMENTS (
      FNAME VARCHAR2(100),
      DOCUMENT CLOB
    )
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
     TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY XML_DIR
     ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        FIELDS (
         FNAME CHAR(100)
       )
       COLUMN TRANSFORMS (
         DOCUMENT FROM lobfile (FNAME)
       )
    )
    LOCATION ('entrypoint.txt')
   )
   /
```

Now try query external table if everything is correct. 
If some exception will be raised. Probably there is typo mistake or you don't have privileges. Externatable read file name from entrypoint.txt and it's using them to read xmlFiles.

Next step parse  clob into xmltype (`xmltype(document)`) and and select node content with `xmltable`.

```
 select src.fname,list.* from XML_external_DOCUMENTS src,xmltable('/root/declaration' passing xmltype(document) columns id number path 'id') list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to open an xml file and parse it in PLSQL : use of DBMS.XMLDOM and XMLPROCESSOR:

```
DECLARE
 myParser DBMS_XMLPARSER.parser;
 ficContent CLOB;
 emptyContent CLOB := empty_clob();
 dom DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument;
 rootElement DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMELEMENT;
 rootName VARCHAR2(100);
 myAttribute VARCHAR2(100);
 nlData DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMNODELIST;
 returnCode NUMBER := 0; 

BEGIN
  myParser := DBMS_XMLPARSER.newParser;
  ficContent := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.Read2Clob('MY_DIR', 'my_file.xml' , '0');

  IF ficContent = emptyContent THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('file not found');
      returnCode := 99;
  ELSE
      DBMS_XMLPARSER.parseBuffer(myParser,ficContent);
      dom := DBMS_XMLPARSER.getDocument(myParser);
      rootElement := DBMS_XMLDOM.getDocumentElement(dom);
      rootName := DBMS_XMLDOM.getTagName(rootElement);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('root: ' || rootName);

      -- get root node attribute

      myAttribute:= DBMS_XMLDOM.getAttribute(rootElement, 'attribute_name');

      -- get nodes value

      nldata := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectNodes(DBMS_XMLDOM.makeNode(dom), '//x-path expression', 'xmlns:nsp="http://somewhere.com if there is any namespace"');

       FOR i IN 0 .. DBMS_XMLDOM.getLength(nldata ) - 1 LOOP 
           nodeValue := DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(DBMS_XMLDOM.Item(nlData, i))); 
       END LOOP;

  END IF;

END;
```